# Bidirectional SSL communication on Android?

Tags: android, security, ssl, https, bidirectional

I would like to send a request to a webserver. It should be secure against Man-In-The-Middle-Attacks. Therefore I have created a SSL certificate on the webserver (https). As a response I would get a random String. This works well.

But how can I secure the response to protect it against MITM-Attacks? How should the response be sent from the webserver to Android and what do I have to configure on Android? Do I have to buy another trusted certificate?

Comment: SSL/TLS established a transport channel which is protected against man in the middle attacks __in both directions__. This means request and response are protected. There is no need for special configurations or additional certificates since SSL/TLS protects always in both directions, i.e. request and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical as-called *1-way TLS* (a.k.a "server certificate authentication") setup a server would listen requests from basically any client, but the clients would only trust the server with a valid certificate. When the client thinks it can trust the received certificate, the communication channel can be opened and it will be encrypted both ways.

As-called *2-way TLS* (a.k.a "client certificate authentication" or "mutual authentication") setup means that both ends present a certificate to the other end. In other words your server would trust only certain clients (the ones that present a valid certificate). This would have no impact on your protection against MITM. You would just be limiting the pool of trusted clients.

So as a conclusion - if your only concern is to protect your communication against MITM-attacks, 1-way TLS is fine.

TLS v1.2: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246

Comment: Great explaination. Thanks

Comment: I don't believe *"1-way TLS"* and *"2-way TLS"* are standard terms used to describe the protocol. Also see [RFC 5246](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246).

Comment: Right, while I'm still not sure if they would be standard terms, I edited the post a little bit and added synonyms for both. On the other hand I've seen literature and online material using those terms including CISSP.